# Name for this non-chord tone: approach by step then leap in the same direction

Tags: nonchord-tones

Is there a name for the non-cord tone that is described as: an approached by step and then a leap in the same direction?

As in (suppose the key of D minor): F-G-D, or D-C#-F?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would be inclined to call it an incomplete neighbor unless there is a more convincing interpretation given context.

Let's take your example, for instance.

[image: incomplete neighbor example]

Now take a look at the following:

[image: complete neighbor example]

You can see how in this example, the G *does* resolve back to the F. In both your example and this modified example, the G is acting as a neighbor tone to the F, but in the case of the former, the dissonance is unresolved. This is considered an incomplete neighbor.

Music isn't so black and white however. A slight modification to your example:

[image: 5-6 exchange example]

Is this still an incomplete neighbor? You could reasonably argue that yes, it is. However, it could instead be interpreted as a 5-6 exchange, a common paradigm during the common practice period, and I think that feels like a more *convincing* interpretation. Neither analysis is *wrong* per se, but one could argue that one is more *convincing* than the other.